# Problem for understand $x^{p^k}=x\pmod p$.

Tags: field-theory

We says that $\mathbb F_{p^k}$ is the splitting field of $x^{p^k}-x$ over $\mathbb F_p$. In other word that $$\mathbb F_q\cong \mathbb F_p[x]/(x^{p^k}-x),$$

but why would that mean that $x^{p^k}\equiv x\pmod p$ since $x$ is even not in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ ? I see what is for example $3^p\equiv 3\pmod p$ since $3\in \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, but for $x^{p^k}\equiv x\pmod p$, I really don't see.

Comment: What is $q$? I think you mean over $\mathbb F_p$, and $q=p^k$.

Comment: Also, $F_{p}[x]/(x^{p^k}-x)$ isn't a field, so that is not what is meant by stating that $F_q$ is the splitting field of $x^{p^k}-x$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I corrected for $p$. I thought that if $f(x)$ is irreducible over a filed K and $\alpha $ a root of $f$ then $K(\alpha )\cong K[x]/(f)$, it's wrong ?

Comment: but What give me trouble is what is the signification of $x^{p^k}\equiv x\pmod p$ if $x\notin \mathbb F_p$ ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that the statement $x^{p^k} \equiv x \mod p$ isn't about polynomials. What that is saying if you take any element of $F_q$, call it $x$ (not a formal variable), then $x^{p^k} - x$ will evaluate to 0. This is not the same as saying $x^{p^k} - x$ is the zero polynomial though.

Answer (score 0):

When we construct a field of order $q=p^k$, we are really just adjoining the root of an irreducible polynomial of degree $k$ over $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$. Since the splitting fields of all monic irreducible degree $k$ polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ are isomorphic, when we say that $\mathbb{F}_q$ is the splitting field of $x^{p^k}-x$, we really mean that you just need to adjoin one root and all the rest will follow. Thus, the proper notation would be $\mathbb{F}_q \cong \mathbb{F}_p[x] / \langle f(x) \rangle$ where $f(x)$ is an degree $k$ irreducible (that divides $x^{p^k}-x$).

In regards to your question, we do indeed have $x^{p^k} \equiv x$ "modulo" some degree $k$ irreducible for all $x \in \mathbb{F}_q$. So, you are correct in noting that $x$ need not be an element of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, but when we talk about the "modulus" of a field extension, we are referring to the irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ with some root $\alpha$ that we adjoin to $\mathbb{F}_p$ to construct our field extension.